# how to get locationId in Google App Engine not using terminal

Tags: python, google-app-engine, location

To use scheduler_v1.CloudSchedulerClient().location_path() in Python I need parent with projectId and LocationId. I know how to get projectId in code and locationId from terminal, but how to do it in my code?

I've tried to check this website(https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.location), but there are no examples, idk what to do with it

```
from google.cloud import scheduler_v1


from google.oauth2 import service_account

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file('/home/myname/folder/service_account.json')
service = googleapiclient.discovery.build('cloudresourcemanager', 'v1', credentials = credentials)
request = service.projects().list()
response = request.execute()
client = scheduler_v1.CloudSchedulerClient()

for project in response['projects']:
    parent = client.location_path(project['projectId'], ['LocationID'])
    for element in client.list_jobs(parent):
        print(element)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not necessary to use `cloudresourcemanager` to get the project ID, instead you can use the App Engine environment variable `GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT`

You can use [App engine admin API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/reference/rest/v1/apps/get) to get the location ID please check this code snippet.

```
    credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
    #start discovery service and use appengine admin API
    service = discovery.build('appengine', 'v1', credentials=credentials, cache_discovery=False)

    #disable cache for app engine std (avoid noise in logs)
    logging.getLogger('googleapiclient.discovery_cache').setLevel(logging.ERROR)

    #take the project ID form the environment variables
    project = os.environ['GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT']

    #get App engine application details
    req = service.apps().get(appsId=project)

    response =req.execute()

    #this is the application location id
    location_id = (response["locationId"])
```

Answer (score 1):

I've recently begun using the `http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/region` endpoint.  While it works in App Engine, it's not explicitly documented right now (but it is documented for Cloud Run: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/container-contract).

The result from that endpoint will be something that looks like this:

```
projects/12345678901234/regions/us-central1
```

Obviously, the region is the last part (`us-central1`).

Here's a sample that I have in Go (remember to set the `Metadata-Flavor` header to `Google`):

```
var region string
{
    domain := "http://metadata.google.internal"
    path := "computeMetadata/v1/instance/region"

    request, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodGet, domain+"/"+path, nil)
    if err != nil {
        logrus.Errorf("Could not create request: %v", err)
        panic(err)
    }
    request.Header.Set("Metadata-Flavor", "Google")
    response, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(request)
    if err != nil {
        logrus.Errorf("Could not perform request: %v", err)
        panic(err)
    }
    contents, err := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
    if err != nil {
        logrus.Errorf("Could not read contents: %v", err)
        panic(err)
    }
    originalRegion := string(contents)
    logrus.Infof("Contents of %q: %s", path, originalRegion)
    parts := strings.Split(originalRegion, "/")
    if len(parts) > 0 {
        region = parts[len(parts)-1]
    }
}
logrus.Infof("Region: %s", region)
```

Answer (score -1):

In Google App Engine, there are some environment variables set by runtime environment.
You can get it by os.environ.get(environment_name).

[https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/runtime#environment_variables](http://environment%20variabbles.)

Comment: link does not open( i have an environment variable, but what does it change?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/runtime

The environment variable GAE_APPLICATION has region name, where you can derive location code.

OR
You can explicitly specify environment variable LOCATION_CODE and use it.

Comment: `GAE_APPLICATION` is basically `${region-code}~${project}`.  Unfortunately, the region code does not map to a location ID, at least not in a way that I've seen documented.  My `us-central1` instance has a region code of `s`.